# Unable to import handlebar file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I am unable to import handlebars file in nodejs. Although it is importing the file but not compiling properly with given data.

here is my test.handlebars file code

`<div>Hey {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</div>`

and this is my index.js file code

```
const Handlebars = require("handlebars");
const testEmailTemplate = require("./email-templates/test.handlebars")
const template = Handlebars.compile(testEmailTemplate());

console.log(template({ firstname: "Nils", lastname: "Test" }));
```

And I am getting below output in console

```
<div>Hey</div>
```

expected output

```
<div>Hey Nils Test</div>
```

Note: - I don't want to use express-handlebar so please suggest some solution only with handlebars.

Comment: if you inspect the result of `testEmailTemplate()` you will notice it's missing the placeholders. `require` is not for reading string files but for loding modules. Read the file with `fs.readFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `require()` method expects to get a Node.js module. But in your case, the target file is HTML, and you need to get the content of the file as plain text to use it further. Use for that `fs` module and it's method [fs.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) or [fs.readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

The result code should look like:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Handlebars = require("handlebars");
const testEmailTemplate = fs.readFileSync("./email-templates/test.handlebars", "utf-8")
const template = Handlebars.compile(testEmailTemplate);

console.log(template({ firstname: "Nils", lastname: "Test" }));
```

Info: [What is require?](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)

Comment: Got it! Thanks Max.